# Can we resume training on MALLET model?

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

I have the -output-model set up. Can we resume the iteration of the Gibbs sampling using that "snapshot"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the saved model is a complete snapshot of the current state. Use `--input-model` to initialize a new run.

Comment: Hi David, thank you! And also for the wonderful MALLET package of your hard work!